# Why is Android Studio giving me problems with my findLongestName method?

Tags: android, arrays, unexpected-token

I've got an array of names that is declared like this:

> String[] names = {"Anja", "Kimberli", "Edmond", "Shenna", "Edythe", "Sherrell", "Lindsay",
>                   "Randee", "Janell", "Jeremy", "Jaqueline", "Clay", "Nakita", "Elina", "Gwenn", 
>                   "Michelle", "Lynsey", "Guy"};

But when I create a method that accepts the names array as a parameter, Android Studio underlines the opening and closing parentheses stating that a "**;** is expected". It also underlines the [] stating this: "**)** and **;** are expected", "expression expected", and "unexpected token".

```
    public String findLongestName(String[] names){

        int sizeOfArray = names.length;
        String longestName = names[0];

        for(int i = 1; i<sizeOfArray; i++){
            longestName = names[i];
            String previousName = names[i-1];
            if(longestName.length()<previousName.length()){
                longestName = names[i];
            }
        }
        return longestName;
    }
```

[image: A photo of the problem]

Comment: up to java  7 nested methods are not supported. Move findLongestName out oncreate

Comment: Wow. I wasted so much time trying to figure out what was going on with my compiler. Thank you.